# Error executing a dynamic query with inner join (VBA) to dynamic tables

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, inner-join

I'm sorry for my English ;)

I have consulted a lot on the internet but I cannot find the solution

I must create a dynamic query, with a function.
This code works for me if the tables are not linked, but are in the same bbdd ACCESS 2016.
But I need them to be in another bbdd.
Can you help me?

It returns me that data is missing.

The query is made in access and modified in vba, adding the variables.

Ano and Trimestre are numerical, the others are text.

```
Public Function PRUEBA_INNER(ByVal TRIMESTRE As String,ByVal ANO As String) As Boolean
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim StrSQL As String
Set db = CurrentDb
    StrSQL = "SELECT " & _
    "PERSONAS.NOMBRE, " & _
    "PERSONAS.MAIL, " & _
    "PERSONAS.[NUMR_COLEG], " & _
    "DATOS_" & ANO & ".ANO, " & _
    "DATOS_" & ANO & ".TRIMESTRE " & _
    "FROM " & _
    "PERSONAS " & _
    "INNER JOIN DATOS_" & ANO & " " & _
    "ON PERSONAS.[NUMR_COLEG] = DATOS_" & ANO & ".NUMR_COLEG " & _
    "GROUP BY " & _
    "PERSONAS.NOMBRE, " & _
    "PERSONAS.MAIL, " & _
    "PERSONAS.[NUMR_COLEG], " & _
    "DATOS_" & ANO & ".ANO, " & _
    "DATOS_" & ANO & ".TRIMESTRE " & _
    "HAVING (((DATOS_" & ANO & ".ANO)=" & ANO & ")" & _
    " AND ((DATOS_" & ANO & ".TRIMESTRE)=" & TRIMESTRE & "))"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(StrSQL)
Do Until rs.EOF
    debug.print rs!nombre
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close: Set rs = Nothing
db.Close: Set db = Nothing
End Function
```

Debug.print:

```
SELECT 
PERSONAS.NOMBRE, 
PERSONAS.MAIL, 
PERSONAS.[NUMR_COLEG], 
DATOS_2018.ANO, 
DATOS_2018.TRIMESTRE 
FROM 
PERSONAS 
INNER JOIN 
DATOS_2018 
ON 
PERSONAS.[NUMR_COLEG] = DATOS_2018.NUMR_COLEG 
GROUP BY 
PERSONAS.NOMBRE, 
PERSONAS.MAIL, 
PERSONAS.[NUMR_COLEG], 
DATOS_2018.ANO, 
DATOS_2018.TRIMESTRE 
HAVING (((DATOS_2018.ANO)=2018) AND ((DATOS_2018.TRIMESTRE)=2))
```

Error message:

```
nº 3061
Few parameters.
1 expected
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: I know may be silly question but you have set links to all backend tables? Make sure the SQL works in a query object.